# How can I add syntax highlighting to vim as I can do in gedit?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

When I write a script in gedit, the commands, comments, variables etc... are given different colors. How do I setup vim to do the same?

Comment: Check out this question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/change-default-syntax-highlighting-scheme

Answer (score 10):

vim has an extensive support for syntax highlighting and typical distributions contain a number of highlighting rules. For enabling this you have to switch the syntax module on using `:syntax on` in your vim session or globally your `.vimrc` file.

See [vim help on syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) for details.

Answer (score 8):

Try `:syntax on`.

To have syntax highlighting enabled by default, add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
```

If the file doesn't exist, create it.