# Change default syntax highlighting scheme

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm unhappy with the default syntax highlighting in vim and would like to change it. I tried to follow the accepted answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890103/change-syntax-color-in-vim), but I think my vim version (7.4) is different.

Inside `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` I have tons of files, so I decided to edit `php.vim`. But I find that the format in the file isn't like the one in the link I mentioned. Here's my [php.vim](http://pastebin.com/jU2bsmMh) file.

Can someone help me figure out how to customize vi syntax highlighting?

Comment: have you tried downloading another color scheme ? you can find some on : http://vimcolors.com/

Comment: It may come as a surprise to you, but syntax files don't specify colours.  What you want to change is your _colours scheme_, not the syntax files. Messing with files in `/usr/share/vim/vim74` is likely to break vim.  Just pick a colour scheme and install that.

Comment: Hmm, the color schemes look interesting, but I'm having trouble installing. I selected https://github.com/scheakur/vim-scheakur and then created `scheakur.vim` inside `~/.vim/colors`. After firing `vim`, I did `set background=light` and `colorscheme scheakur` when the whole (PHP) text became black! What could be wrong?

Comment: can you confirm that you want to change the colorscheme @dotslash ? Because with what you did we got confused ... Did you reset the previous `php.vim` ?

Comment: @Nobe4 Hey, I guess that particular color scheme was broken. I tried another one and it worked! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :-)

Comment: And yes, I did reset `php.vim`

Comment: glad I could help, I recommend watching http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/ if you want to create your own colorscheme :)

Comment: @Nobe4 Superb! I can't express how happy this has made me! :) :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm answering my own question so that it can be closed. All credit to @Nobe4 and @lcd047)

The `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` directory doesn't have colors, surprisingly. What is needed to change syntax highlighting in `vim` is a colorscheme. These can be placed in `~/.vim/colors/` and activated in `vi` with `set syntax on` and `colorscheme cool_color_scheme.vim`. It's also possible to make one's own color schemes; check out http://bytefluent.com/vivify/ for a visual colorscheme maker/editor for vim.